Need 72h of autonomy lithium battery pack for 5V devices
I'm working on a new project that requires power for:

Raspberry Pi 4 (15W = 5v, 3A)
2 fans (0.5 W, 5v, 0.1A)
one video camera (5W = 5v , 1A)

That's in total ~20W. Notice that it seems that the RB4 in average consumes 6W,github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/develop/documentation/… , the camera is up to 7W. https://shop.luxonis.com/products/oak-d-pro
The main issue is that the project
needs to run in the countryside, and because of that and other logistical reasons, the
battery autonomy needs to be 72 hours. Also, the location where
the setup would be is on the heights. Thus, we cannot count
on traditional bulky battery boxes; we need a new design that can adapt
to the bar where the camera is installed.
Therefore, we've chosen 18650 batteries (3.7V 2.6Ah = 9.62Wh), which are
more commercial and can be arranged in different shapes.
So the main issue I see now and what the question is about is,
How to find/design a BMS that can provide that can manage the
power requirement above?
So, I did the following calculations:

72h * 20W = 1440Wh.
1440Wh / 5V = 288Ah.
1440Wh / 9.62Wh ~= 150 battery cells.

In conclusion, I need a battery of 288Ah at least to provide 1440Wh at 5v, using 150 batteries. The available options on Amazon for BMS seems to target too much voltage >3S cells or too low amperage like 20A.  If I'm mistaken in something here, please let me know.

20 W is your maximum power. What's your actual average power? You may be able to get the requirement down significantly.

Good luck building or finding a 5-volt 100-amp or more battery charger.  The output cables will be the size of your thumb. Your terminology is wrong. Batteries are not measured in Amp; try Amp Hours.

For the calculations "1440Wh / 5V" is a result in Amp-hours (Ah), rather than amps (A). Therefore, the BMS doesn't need to support a maximum battery current of 288 A, but rather 20 W / 5 V or 4 A.

Designing a portable battery operated processor based device is not easy. Every situation is likely unique. Professional engineers spend weeks if not months on projects like this. Also, designing for worst case (which appears to be your approach) is not practical (as already pointed out in some comments). I would suggest you examine your use case and add the missing constraints to your question.

@Neil_UK good question, it seems that the RB4 in average consumes 6W,https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/develop/documentation/asciidoc/computers/raspberry-pi/power-supplies.adoc#typical-power-requirements , the camera is up to 7W

@ChesterGillon I fixed the typo, thanks.  Can you elaborate why just 4A? The battery needs to work well for 72hr

@JonathanPrieto-Cubides By "4 A" I meant the minimum discharge current that the battery, and therefore BMS, need to be able to support for a duration of 72 hours. Albeit as per the comment from Neil_UK the average discharge current will be lower.

Have you built the electronics without the battery?  Please measure the ACTUAL consumed current (and check actual input voltage) under any relevant operating conditions.  Also, the battery output will vary and will rarely be 5.0V, so the normal method to build battery powered electronics device is to use a higher voltage battery pack and then convert with DC-DC power converter to the device input voltage.  For example, use a 100Ah 12.8V LiFePO4 battery pack, and then attach a buck DC-DC converter with output of 5V up to at least 4A.
